# How to compile app in iOS 7.1 beta device with Xcode51_Beta

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5

Yesterday I've updated my iphone with latest **iOS 7.1 beta 4**, I know that after doing so, I **could not** compile projects to my device, SO, I downloaded **Xcode51_Beta4**, installed it in my mac, BUT there is **no iOS7.1 simulator**. I opened Preferences/Downloads, also there is no available iOS7.1 simulators. 
How do I get **iOS7.1 SDK** into Xcode51_Beta?

Comment: do you have iOS 7.0 simulator in your xcode ??

Comment: @iOS.Wolf I didn't have yesterday (I tried restarting xcode many times), but now I have. It is downloading now. Will it work for ios7.1 device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One I downloaded iOS 6.1 Simulator, I see also iOS 7.1 simulator. Very strange, but it works.

Comment: I updated iOS 6.1 and didn't find iOS 7.1 in the Xcode.

Comment: Oops. My Xcode version is 5.0.2. Updating the Xcode version to 5.1 done the magic. Wiki helps me find which Xcode version is compatible for iOS 7. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_SDK
Also make sure to install iOS 6.1